# how Convert .ajax() to fetch()

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, fetch

I'm trying to use JavaScript's fetch library to make a form submission to my Django application. However no matter what I do it still complains about CSRF validation.
my code fetch don't work

ajax

```
  function myidLikeCom(params) {

    
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "boards:likeComment" %}',
        data: {
          postid: params,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
          action: 'post'
        },
        success: function (json) {
          document.querySelector(`#myidLikeCom${params}`).innerText = "json['result']";
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
  
        }
      });
    }
```

fetch don't work

```
  function myidLikeCom(params) {
        let data= {
          postid: params,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        }  
fetch('{% url "boards:likeComment" %}', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data, 
})     
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/) for how to pass the CSRF token using AJAX.

You need to pass the token in the appropriate header.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "boards:likeComment" %}',
        headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        data: {
          postid: params,
          action: 'post'
        },
        success: function (json) {
          document.querySelector(`#myidLikeCom${params}`).innerText = "json['result']";
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
  
        }
      });
```

Comment: please convert this code  to fetch